# Firebase How To Retrieve The Data Under A Push Key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't figure out how to retrieve my data without variable under the push key, so please help.

```
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FireAlarm");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot keySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                dataBaru = keySnapshot.getKey();
                data.setText(dataBaru);
            }
        }
```

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: It seems like you've shared wrong screenshot. And could you elaborate the problem with current code?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem

Comment: i want to retrieved the "32cm" (all the data in the apostrophe) from those random push() key. i able to retrieved only the keys but not the data .

Comment: i did some changes to my coding. actually the data is being sent from nodemcu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
dataBaru = keySnapshot.getKey();
```

You are getting only those pushed keys. If you want to get the values corresponding to the keys, please use the following line of code:

```
dataBaru = keySnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

One more thing, when looping through a `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method, you're most likely getting more than one result so you can simply set it to a `TextView`. So probably you should use a `ListView` for that or even better a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: thanks for the help , it works , planning on using recyclerview instead :)

Comment: For a `RecyclerView`, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase realtime database using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.